# Add php5-imagick to Heroku php buildpack

Tags: php, heroku, imagick, heroku-api

Someone can show me how to customize the official buildpack `heroku/php` in order to add php5-imagick extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to customize the buildpack. The extension is already supported.

Just follow the instructions in the docs, https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions

Your `composer.json` needs `ext-imagick` in the `require` section; the next deploy will then have the extension enabled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Add `imagick` to your `composer.json` file as noted in the Heroku PHP support document: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support